# Index into list in multiple places in Python?

Tags: python

Say I have two lists A which has 10 elements, and I want to assign the list `B = [x1, y1]` to values in A.  If the values are sequential, it is straightforward e.g. `A[1:3] = B`.  But what if my indices are non-sequential?  In MATLAB I can do `A([3 10]) = B;`, is there an equivalently clean Python solution?  The for loop to do this is straightforward, but I am wondering if I am missing something more "Pythonic".

Comment: Adding examples of input and output would help understand your question

Comment: I couldn't get what 'assigning' meant.

Comment: How is `A([3 10])` not a sequential list?  It's possible, but we'd have to understand the analog (for those of us who've never seen MATLAB syntax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly more verbose, but you can use tuple unpacking to assign to new indices:

```
>>> x = range(1, 11)
>>> x[3], x[7] = 99, 999
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 99, 5, 6, 7, 999, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I try to emulate some Matlab functionality in Python I use numpy. Using a numpy [`array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html) instead of a python `list` allows to you get the functionality you are looking for with almost the same syntax as Matlab:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(10)

In [3]: b = [200, 300]

In [4]: a[[2, 9]] = b

In [5]: a
Out[5]: array([  0,   1, 200,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8, 300])
```